# "Mein Kind zum Arzt bringen"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference, word-choice, verb

Ich kann den Unterschied zwischen den Wörtern *bringen*, *mitbringen*, *nehmen* und *mitnehmen* nicht genau verstehen.

Schreibt man „mein Kind zum Arzt bringen“?

Oder kann man auch „mein Kind zum Arzt mitbringen / nehmen / mitnehmen“ schreiben?

Könnte jemand mir bitte den Unterschied deutlich erklären?

Answer (score 12):

Da gibt es durchaus gewisse Bedeutungsunterschiede. Eine Ausnahme ist "mein Kind zum Arzt **nehmen**" - das kann man vielleicht in der Umgangssprache hören, ist aber falsch.

- "mein Kind **zum Arzt bringen**": ich gehe mit meinem Kind zur Arztpraxis; das Kind "steht im Vordergrund", es benötigt ärztliche Hilfe. Es kann (oder will) nicht selbstständig zum Arzt gehen, deswegen bringe ich es. Jemanden, der selbstständig den Arzt aufsuchen kann, könnte man "zum Arzt schicken"; wer dies nicht kann, den sollte man dorthin bringen.
- "mein Kind **zum Arzt mitbringen / mitnehmen**": ich selber möchte den Arzt aufsuchen und könnte dies grundsätzlich auch alleine. Ich sorge dafür, dass mein Kind mich dorthin begleitet, etwa weil ich es nicht unbeaufsichtigt lassen möchte (wenn es sehr klein ist), oder weil es mir helfen kann (wenn es schon größer ist).
- "**Mitnehmen**" kann man auch jemanden, der dasselbe Ziel hat wie man selber. Bei dem Arzttermin ist das unwahrscheinlich, aber man könnte jemanden auf einen Ausflug, in die Stadt oder auf dem Heimweg mitnehmen.

Comment: Ja, die *Bedeutungs*unterschiede sind gering. Ich kann auch sagen: "Ich muss mein Kind zum Arzt nehmen", und jedermann versteht es. In der Tat sprechen Leute, die Deutsch erst spät und nicht sehr gründlich gelernt haben, oft so. Jedoch genau hieran erkennt man Sprachbeherrschung. Will man nicht als radebrechend Deutsch Sprechender angesehen werden, muss man die Wörter richtig einsetzen, auch wenn es für die reine Sache (Information über die Absicht, mit dem Kind zum Arzt zu gehen) nicht notwendig wäre. - Für eine gute Note in einem Deutschkurs muss man so etwas ebenfalls können.

Answer (score 8):

Die Situationen der Verwendung dieser Wörter sind verschieden.

*Bringen* und *nehmen* unterscheiden sich in der Perspektive auf **Zielort** (bringen, "zu einem Ort hin") und **Startort** (nehmen, "von einem Ort weg").

*Mit* kennzeichnet dabei, dass die Ortsverlagerung des Gegenstands (hier: des Kindes) für den Sprecher nicht den Kern der Handlung darstellt sondern eher eine **Nebenhandlung** (mitbringen vs. bringen, mitnehmen vs. nehmen).

Doch genug der Theorie. Wohlgeformte, alltagstaugliche Sätze sind:

> Ich **bringe** mein Kind zum Arzt.

wenn das Kind krank ist und zum Arzt soll [Zielort]. Aber

> Ich **nehme** mein Kind **mit** zum Arzt.

wenn ich selbst zum Arzt muss, das Kind jedoch nicht zuhause lassen kann. (Hauptfokus: Ich gehe zum Arzt. Nebenhandlung: Ich nehme das Kind mit.) Nota bene: Es geht nicht darum, dass das Kind zum Arzt [Zielort] kommt, sondern darum, dass es nicht alleine zuhause rumsitzt [Startort].

Aus Sicht der Sprechstundenhilfe beim Arzt hieße es dann jedoch:

> Frau Müller hat ihr Kind **mitgebracht**.

(Hauptfokus: Frau Müller ist gekommen. Nebenhandlung: Sie hat auch ihr Kind dabei, und nun haben wir es hier [Zielort].)

Geht es jedoch - wie im ersten Beispiel - um das Kind selber, das der Arzt sich mal anschauen sollte, dann sagt die Sprechstundenhilfe zum Arzt:

> Frau Müller hat ihr Kind **gebracht**.

(Hauptfokus bzw. einziger Fokus: Das Kind ist hier [Zielort].)

Die Sprechstundenhilfe würde dagegen sagen

> Frau Müller hat ihr Kind **mitgenommen**.

wenn Frau Müller irgendwie anwesend war, und zwar samt Kind, nun aber wieder weg ist und dabei auch das Kind mitgenommen hat. Konkrete Situation: Sagen wir, es war vereinbart, dass Frau Müller das Kind in der Spielecke im Wartezimmer lässt und derweil zum Einkaufen geht, aber dann stellt die Sprechstundenhilfe erstaunt fest, dass Frau Müller gegangen ist und ihr Kind offenbar *mitgenommen* hat. (Hauptfokus: Frau Müller ist weg. Nebenhandlung: Und dabei hat sie auch noch ihr Kind aus dem Wartezimmer [Startort] mitgenommen.)

Der Arzt wiederum könnte sagen:

> Frau Müllers Kind sieht **mitgenommen** aus.

wenn es einen schlechten, müden, angestrengten, schlappen Eindruck macht. Das ist nun aber natürlich nicht mehr im Sinne der direkten Wortbedeutung. Vielmehr handelt es sich um den Ausdruck *mitgenommen sein/aussehen*, der etwa gleichbedeutend ist mit *geschlaucht sein/aussehen*.

(Allerdings konnte der Arzt das Kind ja gar nicht sehen, denn Frau Müller hat es ja gleich wieder *mitgenommen* [vom Startort] und vermutlich nach Hause *gebracht* [zum Zielort].)

---

**Übung**

> Tante Hildegard kommt zu Besuch. "Hier, Kinder, ich habe euch etwas ........!" [genommen / mitgenommen / gebracht / mitgebracht]
>
> Paul hat seine abgelaufenen Schuhe zum Schuster ....... , um sie neu besohlen zu lassen. [genommen / mitgenommen / gebracht / mitgebracht]
>
> Der Klempner ist sicher, dass er die Rohrzange aus der Werkstatt ..........  hat, aber nun findet er sie im ganzen Auto nicht. [genommen / mitgenommen / gebracht / mitgebracht]
>
> Ehepaar Müller verlässt das Haus, um einen Ausflug zu machen. Frau Müller ruft von der Hofeinfahrt ihrem Mann zu: "....... du bitte den Haustürschlüssel mit?" [nimmst / bringst]
>
> Fritz und Helga sind ins Freibad gefahren. Sie liegen auf der Wiese. Auf einmal sagt Helga: "He, Fritz, haben wir eigentlich das Gummikrokodil ......... ?" [genommen / mitgenommen / gebracht / mitgebracht]

Wichtig: Nicht in allen Fällen gibt es eine richtige und falsche Antwort. Oft kommt es auf die Perspektive an: Was will man genau sagen? Wo liegt für einen selber der Fokus?

Comment: Oh, da war jemand 16 Sekunden schneller...

Comment: Scnelligkeit ist eine Zier, doch später kommt man ohne ihr.